# Консольная игра. С++ Поле и персонаж.

Tags: c++

Как прорисовывать только Персонажа каждый тик времени, но не прорысовывая поле каждый раз? Ну например: есть двумерный массив, в нём определённая координата есть персонажем. Как мне прорисовать персонажа отдельно?

Comment: Ваш вопрос довольно мутно сформулирован, но для рисования в консоли попробуйте посмотреть на библиотеку ncurses.

Comment: @alexolut, да, не толком ясно, что я хочу, не знаю как верное описать то, что мне нужно)

Comment: Зависит от того, где работаете. В Windows есть пачка консольных функций для вывода в определенном месте символов с определенными атрибутами. Если я правильно понял, что у вас консольная, т.е. в текстовом режиме игра...

Comment: Так вы опишите, на каких технологиях игра делается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, но попробую ответить как понял.

Поле отрисовывается лишь один раз. Прежде чем нарисовать персонажа, нужно сохранить кусочек поля, где он нарисован, в матрицу. Затем, когда персонажа нужно нарисовать снова (например, в другом месте или в другой позе), нужно закрасить кусочек поля (данными из матрицы). Таким образом, перед каждой прорисовкой персонажа просто сохраняете кусочек поля, а потом загружаете его обратно - всё поле при этом не перерисовывается.

Для кусочка поля и хранения самого персонажа матрица желательно чтобы была прямоугольной.

Что касается технических аспектов бытия... это зависит от средств технологий, которыми вы пользуетесь. А вы их не указали.